# How to use Xpath to lookup field and click button in the same row

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I need to navigate to a website, create an entry and then delete the same entry. The problem I'm facing is the unique ID in the Xpath of the Delete button changes with each new entry and there are multiple Delete buttons on the website. What I'd like to do is tell Xpath to look at the first name field and click on the delete button in the same row. Here's my code - it runs without errors and creates the new entry, however it doesn't delete the entry after the page refresh.

Here's an example of the Xpaths for the firstname field and Delete button

```
Firstname: //*[@id="6178"]/div[1]/p

Delete button: //*[@id="6178"]/div[7]/input
```

(Extremely new to Java so please go easy on me).
[image]

```
private WebDriver driver;


public void setUp() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "resources/chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://xyz.io/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.findElement(By.id("firstname")).sendKeys("JohnHotelBooking");
    driver.findElement(By.id("lastname")).sendKeys("Smith");
    driver.findElement(By.id("totalprice")).sendKeys("1500");
    driver.findElement(By.id("checkin")).sendKeys("2021-09-03");
    driver.findElement(By.id("checkout")).sendKeys("2021-09-05");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[7]/input")).click();
    driver.navigate().refresh();
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    SaveAndDelete test = new SaveAndDelete();           //create instance of class
    test.setUp();
}

public void DeleteByFirstName(String firstname)
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'" + firstname + "')]/ancestor::div[contains(text(),'JohnHotelBooking')]//div[contains(@class,'col-md-1')][contains(.,'Delete')]")).click();
    DeleteByFirstName("JohnHotelBooking");
}
```

HTML as requested:

```
<div class="row" id="6178">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <p>JohnHotelBooking</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <p>Smith</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <p>1500</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <p>true</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <p>2021-09-03</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <p>2021-09-05</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <input type="button" onclick="deleteBooking(6178)" value="Delete">
    </div>
</div>
```

**TIDIED UP VERSION**

```
private WebDriver driver;

public void setUp() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "resources/chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("xyz/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}

    @Test //add test
            public void testAddEntry(){
    driver.findElement(By.id("firstname")).sendKeys("JohnHotelBooking");
    driver.findElement(By.id("lastname")).sendKeys("Smith");
    driver.findElement(By.id("totalprice")).sendKeys("1500");
    driver.findElement(By.id("checkin")).sendKeys("2021-09-03");
    driver.findElement(By.id("checkout")).sendKeys("2021-09-05");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[7]/input")).click();
    driver.navigate().refresh();
}

    @Test //delete test

    public void deleteByFirstName(String firstname)
    {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='row'][./div[1]/p[text()='" + firstname + "']]/div/input[@value='Delete']")).click();
    }


public static void main(String args[]) {
    SaveAndDelete test = new SaveAndDelete();           
    test.setUp();
    test.testAddEntry();
    test.deleteByFirstName("JohnHotelBooking");
}
```

}

Comment: Hi Lisa , as per your code, you didn't call your deleteByFirstName method anywhere.

anyway if you using it and did not attached here. so can you please create more than 1 record/entry and attached the DOM from the parent of the record. so we can analyze the XPath.

Comment: Hey @ICanDebuggIt sorry about that - copied the last bit where I'm calling the method. Also attached screenshot and XPath examples from an entry I created. Hope this helps?

Comment: Please post the HTML of a row as text in your answer so we can test and create an XPath.

Comment: In your answer... properly formatted. That way future readers don't have to look at all comments to get all the info needed to answer your question. You can use an online tool like https://beautifytools.com/html-beautifier.php to format it.

Comment: Thanks Jeff - have updated. This ok?

Comment: Yes, working on answer. I fixed the formatting of the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to your question is

```
public void DeleteByFirstName(String firstname)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    By locator = By.xpath("//div[@class='row'][./div[1]/p[text()='" + firstname + "']]/div/input[@value='Delete']");
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator)).click();
}
```

The XPath breaks down to

```
//div[@class='row'][./div[1]/p[text()='" + firstname + "']]/div/input[@value='Delete']
^ find a DIV that has the class 'row' (the parent DIV)
                   ^ the parent DIV's first DIV child has a child P that contains the first name
                                                           ^ once the parent DIV is found, find the DIV child that has an INPUT child
```

Hopefully that makes sense. Ask questions if you need more description.

You'll need to add a call to `DeleteByFirstName()` from your test because it's missing right now.

---

There are other issues that I'd like to bring up to make your tests better.

1. You really should be searching for more than just first name. If you look in your bed of test data, you can see there are multiple "Dave"s. I would suggest you should search by all columns to ensure that you get the right person. This can be easily accomplished by a more expanded XPath. Let me know if you want that also.
2. `setUp()` is intended to be run at the start of each test. It should NOT have test steps in it like filling in the form with test data, etc. It should be setting up the browser and possibly navigating to the hotel booking form.

   ```
    public void setUp() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "resources/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://hotel-test.equalexperts.io/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
   ```

   The rest of the code should go in the test itself.
3. You should look into using TestNG or JUnit to help create and run tests. I prefer TestNG but both have a TON of functionality that will be useful to you.
4. Your `DeleteByFirstName()` is calling itself in line 2 of that method.
5. Look into the page object model. It will significantly help you create tests faster, keep things better organized, and easier to maintain.

Comment: Thank you so much Jeff. I've tidied up a bit and added it below the original (TIDIED UP VERSION). 
I'm using a factitious first name (JohnHotelBooking) so that I can immediately look that name up and delete it again. to prevent issues such as multiple Daves.
I've run the tidied up version now but the following error is being returned:

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='row'][./div[1]/p[text()='JohnHotelBooking']]/div/input[@value='Delete']"}

Comment: My guess is that you're script is running faster than the page and you need to add a wait to `DeleteByFirstName()`. I've updated the method in my answer. See if that works.

Answer (score 1):

let's go step by step.

1. as you have 'SetUp' method : used to create webdriver instance and creating record.
   then you are call that into the main method, but your code is not calling DeleteByFirstName any where in main.
2. your code is calling DeleteByFirstName inside the same 'DeleteByFirstName' method only.

it should be something like.

```
public void setUp() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "resources/chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://hotel-test.equalexperts.io/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.findElement(By.id("firstname")).sendKeys("JohnHotelBooking");
    driver.findElement(By.id("lastname")).sendKeys("Smith");
    driver.findElement(By.id("totalprice")).sendKeys("1500");
    driver.findElement(By.id("checkin")).sendKeys("2021-09-03");
    driver.findElement(By.id("checkout")).sendKeys("2021-09-05");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[7]/input")).click();
    driver.navigate().refresh();
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    SaveAndDelete test = new SaveAndDelete();           //create instance of class
    test.setUp();
    test.DeleteByFirstName("JohnHotelBooking"); // now code is calling deleteByFirstName method
}

public void DeleteByFirstName(String firstname)
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'" + firstname + "')]/ancestor::div[contains(text(),'JohnHotelBooking')]//div[contains(@class,'col-md-1')][contains(.,'Delete')]")).click();
}
```

3. Next check the below xpath. open the developer tool and paste this xpath into developer option.

   //p[text()='Smith']/following-sibling::p[text()='1500']/following-sibling::p[text()='true']
   /following-sibling::p[text()='2021-09-03']/following-sibling::p[text()='2021-09-05']
   /ancestor::div[@class='row']//input[@type='button' @value='Delete']

please test and verify the above xpath is able to identify the record for [Smith:1500:true:2021-09-03:2021-09-05]. and the number of the matched element is '1 of 1' if yes then this xpath can be short and used based on some specific details.

4. Else we can have list of all the element which focus on the delete button on DOM. collect all by findElements() :: return List. then click on index 0 WebElement. these are some workaround can be used.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks so much for the tips. I tested option 3 - XPath wasn't able to identify the record. I've updated my question with a tidied up version, but I'm getting an error now:

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='row'][./div[1]/p[text()='JohnHotelBooking']]/div/input[@value='Delete']"}